# Kernel Error: Failed to start - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror

I did a decent amount of searching before posting, and I can’t seem to find anyone with the same exact problem, or at least a similar problem with a solution that works for me.

My Kernel is failing to start when I try to run an ipynb in jupyter notebook. I’m getting this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

These are all of my version numbers:

```
jupyter core : 4.6.3 
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3 
qtconsole : 4.7.3
ipython : 7.14.0 
ipykernel : 5.2.1 
jupyter client : 6.1.3 
jupyter lab : 2.1.1 
nbconvert : 5.6.1 
ipywidgets : 7.5.1 
nbformat : 5.0.6
traitlets : 4.3.3
```

I'm using Python 3.8.2, windows 10, and have tried running Jupyter Notebook from cmd, and also the powershell in VS Code with the same results.